# BadRequest on /metrics REST endpoint in Azure

Tags: api, rest, azure

I'm trying to access the metrics using the Azure Insights API as per the following MSDN [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/02/23/retrieving-resource-metrics-via-the-azure-insights-api/).

My Request URL is:

> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscription-id/resourceGroups/resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachine/myVM/metrics?api-version=2016-03-30

with proper Accept and Authorization headers.

The same thing works for metricDefinitions and I get back a bunch of MetricDefinitions. But when I try to access the /metrics endpoint, I get back this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "The request URL is not valid."
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to know what am I doing wrong in the request?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the metric's name for any filtering requests. But there is no metric specifed in your URL, which leads to an invalid URL. For example, you want to retreive the CpuTime metric data point, the request url should be like below:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscription-id/resourceGroups/resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachine/myVM/metrics?api-version=2016-03-30&$filter=%28name.value%20eq%20%27CpuTime%27%20
```

Comment: Tried what you mentioned. Didn't work. It's still giving me the same "Bad Request" response.